# VM Crash when call java function from js using phonegap api

Tags: android

I had using phonegap to program one apps that try to call java function from the java script in the android 2.3.3 environment.

My problem was the the app show alert message and then crash and prompted error message below

```
    08-04 11:06:12.669: W/dalvikvm(551): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x40522898 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
    08-04 11:06:12.669: I/dalvikvm(551): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
    08-04 11:06:12.669: I/dalvikvm(551):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051dd20 self=0x2a6d88
    08-04 11:06:12.669: I/dalvikvm(551):   | sysTid=559 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2780864
    08-04 11:06:12.669: I/dalvikvm(551):   | schedstat=( 943171212 746714576 110 )
    08-04 11:06:12.680: I/dalvikvm(551):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
    08-04 11:06:12.680: I/dalvikvm(551):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
    08-04 11:06:12.680: I/dalvikvm(551):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:53)
    08-04 11:06:12.680: I/dalvikvm(551):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1158)
    08-04 11:06:12.680: I/dalvikvm(551):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-04 11:06:12.680: I/dalvikvm(551):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    08-04 11:06:12.680: I/dalvikvm(551):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
    08-04 11:06:12.680: I/dalvikvm(551):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    08-04 11:06:12.680: E/dalvikvm(551): VM aborting
```

Can anyone help/advice on this issue?

Below is the code

```
 MainActivity.java

        import org.apache.cordova.*;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

        public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
            private MyClass mc;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                super.init(); 
                mc = new MyClass(this, appView);
                appView.addJavascriptInterface(mc, "MyCls");       
                super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/5.html");
            }  

        }


    MyClass.java

        import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
        import android.webkit.WebView;

        public class MyClass {
              private WebView mAppView;
              private DroidGap mGap;

              public MyClass(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
              {
                mAppView = view;
                mGap = gap;
                System.out.println("jjjjj");
              }

              public String getTelephoneNumber(){
                  return "i am android";
              }
            }

    5.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">      
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.jsonp.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#c2").click(function(){
            alert('jjjj');
            var t = window.MyCls.getTelephoneNumber();
            alert(t );
        });
    });
    </script>

    <body>
    <br><button id="c2">Call Android Activity</button>
    </body>
    </html>

    Manifest:

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.myfirstapp"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="MainActivity" />
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            </activity>
        </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had found out. This issue only happen on the android simulator. It was working fine in the device with android 2.3.4 and 4.0.3.